# Probability of two pairs giving equal sum

Tags: probability, arithmetic

Given four different natural numbers $v1, v2, v3, v4\in [0, n]$ ($n$ is any finite number), what is the probability of $v1 + v2 = v3 + v4$.

I'm trying to know the probability of collision of a hash function of mine and I've reduced my problem to calculate that specific situation.

**NOTE**: I don't know if the numbers being bounded by an interval matters, but I've added it just in case. If that can change, refine or simplify the probability calculation, $n$ is actually $2^x$ where $x$ is probably 64.

**NOTE**: If applying some efficient bit-wise operation (like $XOR$, or $AND$), or multiplying, instead of summing, could reduce drastically the probability of collision, a comment will be appreciated.

Comment: You say $[0,n]$.  Are you meaning this as a range of real numbers?  Or are you meaning this as a range of *integers*?

Comment: @JMoravitz sorry, I meant natural numbers. Edited now.

Comment: If $n$ is unbounded, the probability must be $0$.

Comment: If you’re adding two 64-bit integers and putting the result in another 64-bit integer you should specify how overflow is handled.

Comment: @DavidK Circularly, starting by 0 after overflow. I don't think that matters too much. If they sum differently, their values after overflow will be different as well.

Comment: @Peregring-lk: it does matter. If addition is with saturation, overflow will result in a large number of collisions. If addition is with wraparound, it amounts to a $XOR$. Other rules may have other effects.

Comment: @YvesDaoust In this case is without saturation, but with modular arithmetic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of all the quadruples in  $[0,n]$ is clearly
$$
\left( {n + 1} \right)^{\,4} 
$$

The number of couples satisfyng
$$
\left\{ \matrix{
  0 \le v_{\,1} ,v_{\,2}  \le n \hfill \cr 
  v_{\,1}  + v_{\,2}  = s \hfill \cr}  \right.
$$
is
$$
\left\{ {\matrix{
   {s + 1} & {\left| {\,0 \le s \le n} \right.}  \cr 
   {2n - s + 1} & {\left| {\,n < s \le 2n} \right.}  \cr 
 } } \right.
$$
as can be verified geometrically, drawing the line $v_{\,1}  + v_{\,2}  = s$ inside the square $[0,n]^2$.

Same for $v_{\,3}  + v_{\,4}  = s$.

Therefore the number of ways to have $v_{\,1}  + v_{\,2}  = v_{\,3}  + v_{\,4}  = s$ will be
the square of the above, and the total will be given by the sum over $s$, i.e.
$$
\eqalign{
  & 2\sum\limits_{s = 0}^{n - 1} {\left( {s + 1} \right)^{\,2} }  + \left( {n + 1} \right)^{\,2}  = {{n\left( {2n + 1} \right)\left( {n + 1} \right)} \over 3} + \left( {n + 1} \right)^{\,2}  =   \cr 
  &  = {{\left( {n + 1} \right)\left( {2n^{\,2}  + 4n + 3} \right)} \over 3} \cr} 
$$

Thus the probability you are looking for is
$$
p(n) = {{2n^{\,2}  + 4n + 3} \over {3\left( {n + 1} \right)^{\,3} }}
$$

Answer (score 1):

If your numbers are uniformly distributed in $ i \in [-n,n]$,  $P(v_1 + v_2 = n + i) = (n - \mid i \mid))/(n + 1)^2 $ where $\mid x \mid$ is the asolute value of $x$ ans you also have 
 $$P(v_1 + v_2 = v_3 + v_4) = \sum_{i = -n}^n P(v_1 + v_2 = n + i)  P(v_3 + v_4 = n + i)$$
Then you combine both expressions above, you have
$$P(v_1 + v_2 = v_3 + v_4) = \frac{2 * \sum_{i = 1}^n i^2}{(n + 1)^4} + 1/(n+1)^4 = \frac{n (n + 1) (2 n + 1)}{3 (n + 1)^4} + 1/(n +1)^4 $$

Comment: @YvesDaoust I think his calculations are correct, since he is expressing the sum of two numbers as n plus a modifier that causes the sum to go from 0 to 2n, as expected.

Comment: @YvesDaoust $i$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Numbers are between $[0, n]$, the sum between two numbers is from $[0, 2n]$, and the sum $n+i\in[0,2n]$ since $i\in[-n,n]$.

Answer (score 1):

I’ll use the convention that the hash values are in $S=[0,n),$ also known as $[0,n-1].$
I’ll also assume addition is modulo $n.$
This fits with a typical unsigned integer implementation in a computer.

Then if $v_1$ and $v_2$ are each independently uniformly distributed over $S,$
their sum $v_1+v_2\pmod n$ is also uniformly distributed over $S.$
Then regardless of how we got $v_3$ and $v_4,$
the probability that the sum  $v_1+v_2\pmod n$ 
equals the sum  $v_3+v_4\pmod n$ 
is $1/n.$

---

In fact it’s enough if only one of the four numbers, say $v_1,$ is uniformly distributed, as long as it is not dependent on any of the other numbers. Regardless of what $v_2$ is,
every number in $S$ is the sum modulo $n$ of $v_2$ and a unique value of $v_1,$
so each number has an equal chance to be the sum.

---

The final probability is the same if you use XOR instead of addition, for much the same reasons, because for any integer $v_2$ in $S,$ every other integer in $S$ is the XOR of  $v_2$ and some unique integer in $S$.